# What is the alternative method in HarmonyOS for imageview.getImageMatrix( ) in AndroidOS

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

In Android we will use *getImageMatrix( )* method on *imageView* which returns view's optional matrix. This is applied to the view's drawable when it is drawn. If there is no matrix, this method will return an identity matrix.
In Android:

```
Matrix matrix = imageView.getImageMatrix( ).
```

What is the alternative for this code snippet in HarmonyOS?

Comment: As HarmonyOS claims it has no relation to Android and written from scratch, there should be no alternative to getImageMatrix(). And there should be no alternative to imageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AIMIN pointed out, currently Harmony don't have exact alternative for **ImageView.getImageMatrix()**.

But we will be able to compute **getImageMatrix()** for an **Image** Component. Refer this **PhotoView** Implementation

https://gitee.com/openharmony-tpc/PhotoView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/PhotoView.java